# Transfer file requests to folder using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have no understanding at all on how to make/modify an htaccess rewrite rule, and I havent found anything to this specific issue.

I need to change

site.com/file.php 
to
site.com/folder/file

So the .php also has to go. It needs to work for all files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Come on, there are plenty of examples for that. A little research and effort would be better.

Anyway, here is how your htaccess (in root folder) should look like

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/([^/]+)\.php(?:\s|\?) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /folder/%1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^folder/([^/]+)$ /$1.php [L]
```

Comment: Thanks! And how could I make it so that I didn't have to type the .php extension? So:

site.com/file
to
site.com/folder/file (of course, the file's real name is file.php, but I dont want the .php to appear in the url nor do I want to type it)

Comment: This is already what my code does. It redirects `/file.php` to `/folder/file` and it also internally rewrites back `/folder/file` to `/file.php`